# Можно ли как-то добавлять товар в корзину OZON через Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

Мне надо написать скрипт для добавления в корзину товара, но при написании я столкнулся с проблемой, что при открытии браузера OZON пишет что произошла ошибка и никакие кнопки не нажимаются. Я понимаю что это защита от того же selenium, но есть ли вариант как это сделать?